# airline in conemu - changed colors on page scroll

Tags: vim, cmd, conemu, vim-airline

I have finally got the vim with airline plugin to wok on windows with conemu thanks to this topic: https://github.com/bling/vim-airline/issues/513

Almost everythink is good right now except some problems with colors in the airline when screen is scrolled. Check below gif:
[image]

I'm looking forward to find the culprit.
At the beginning result was worse, but I commented everything that was reduntant. In spare time I will check each and every single setting the the vimrc file. But still can't get the airline to hold his colors.

My vimrc: https://gist.github.com/lkurylo/aa947a1ae6d7185aa064

Comment: You should use Airline's issue tracker.

Comment: I did already. But I hope I will get more response by posting this here too.

Comment: I don't think you will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been fixed in ConEmu 151025